# How to limit column height to another one's?

Tags: wpf, grid, datatemplate

I have a grid in WPF which is made of 4 rows along 2 columns where column 1 holds an Image control and column 2 holds 4 Textblocks. Problem is, the Image control sizes itself to the Image size and extends the listbox's entry too much [Its in a DataTemplate] and makes everything look distorted. I dont want to manually set a max height/width because i want the Image to size itself to the size of the 4 textblocks that are alongside it. Any ideas?

```
<DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Logo, Converter={StaticResource BSConverter}}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" 
                           Grid.Column="0" Stretch="Uniform" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Author}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Version}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Grid.IsSharedSizeGroup on the Parent ListBox to make sure all of your items get the same Width for the first Column like this

```
<ListBox ...
         Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="GroupA"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                ...
```

For the Image height problem, you could bind Height to the ActualHeight of the Parent Grid with a FallbackValue of 1.0 (to ensure the Height of the Image doesn't effect the Height of the Grid)

```
<Image Source="{Binding Logo, Converter={StaticResource BSConverter}}"
       Grid.Row="0"
       Grid.RowSpan="4"
       Grid.Column="0"
       Stretch="Uniform" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
       Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid},
                        Path=ActualHeight,
                        FallbackValue=1.0}"/>
```

Comment: I don't believe this is an issue with regards to the ListBox; granted the OP mentioned that it resides in a ListBox but I believe what the OP is referencing is the row height being modified within the Grid once an Image is added which spans those 4 rows, versus the Image adhering to the overall height and not increasing said height; since a ColumnDefinition does not even have a height property

Comment: I am trying this right now, thanks :) @Aaron I am reffering to the column height as in  the combined height of all of its rows :)

Comment: @Aaron: I missread the question at first and then I updated my answer and didn't remove the first part since that might be a problem for the OP as well. Did you refer to my post before or after the update?

Comment: @Drknezz: I got the wrong idea about your problem at first so maybe the first part doesn't apply. The second part will hopefully solve your problem though:) Should I remove the part about IsSharedSizeScope?

Comment: @Meleak I was referring to the first portion; I had not seen the second portion...

Comment: @Meleak Thanks the binding made it :)

Comment: @Meleak When trying your second portion I had expanded height within the rows relative to the image...ie...the TextBlock's are not butted against each other top to bottom...but apparently this worked for the OP...would be interested in figuring out why this is not working for me though....hmm....

Comment: @Aaron: Did you include the FallbackValue=1.0 in the Binding? Otherwise the Binding would fail the first time, causing it to use its own Height which would expand the Height of the Grid before it could use it as source for the Binding.

Comment: @Aaron: Ok, that's weird. Works fine for me. Might be other factors involved here. Let me know how you do on your second attempt :) If you're curious about the reason I could upload my sample app

Comment: @Meleak Here is my code...https://gist.github.com/758671 Not in a DataTemplate and you will need to swap in your own Image...let me know if it works for you...

Comment: @Aaron: It depends on the parent container so in your case my solution doesn't work since the Grid will consume all available space. If you wrap the Grid in a StackPanel it works.

Comment: @Meleak Yeah that works...wrapping it in a StackPanel; feeling better now on why it was behaving as it was since the Grid will consume all space as you mentioned...thanks for obliging me...

Answer (score 2):

Modifying your containers slightly to make use of a `StackPanel` in conjunction with a `Grid` and referencing the `StackPanel` via `ElementName` binding should provide you the visuals you are looking for...

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,8,0" Source="{Binding Logo, Converter={StaticResource BSConverter}}" 
                           Grid.Column="0" Stretch="Uniform" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
           Height="{Binding ElementName=Contents, Path=ActualHeight}"/>

        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="Contents" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Author}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Version}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```